# Sorting And More Data Available Behavior

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Have a few questions about the API behavior. Say for example, I'm calling Retrieve on ListSubscriber:

1) Are results sorted in any default manner?

2) Is there a way to call the API with a default sorting behavior?

3) If the response returns "MoreDataAvaiable", what would you pass in subsequent calls to retrieve the additional data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to "sort" the results that are returned.  It is my understanding that it is just pulling back 2500 rows of data directly on the database based on how it is stored on the Marketing Cloud's end.

If you receive the response "MoreDataAvailable", you would need to use a continue request in order to continue to pull back anything over 2500 rows of data.  See below links for some information on how to achieve this:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieve_a_subscriber_via_the_web_service_api/

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/continuerequest_2500records/